# How to determine which section header in UITableView is being edited

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, uitextfield

I have a UITextField in a custom section header. There are multiple sections using this style of header, and therefore multiple UITextFields.

I have implemented the UITextFieldDelegate. When I edit one of these UITextFields, it calls the delegate method textFieldDidEndEditing. How do I determine which section header this UITextField was in? I need to save the value to core data in the appropriate NSManagedObject for that section.

Many thanks in advance

EDIT: Several people have suggested using a tag of the section number when creating the cell, which would work perfectly. However, I have already assigned the UITextField a tag to distinguish it as a 'header' textfield as opposed to a cell textfield or a 'footer' textfield. There are a whole lotta textfields on this table!!

Further EDIT: Using in indexPath has been suggested. This would be my preferred solution if I can get it to work. Does anyone know if headers and footers have indexPaths?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use tags to identify `UITextField` instances. Since you're already setting tags in `UITextField` instances, set the tags on the section views itself:

```
- (UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
  UIView *sectionView = ... // your section view instance

  // assign the section index as the tag
  sectionView.tag = section; 

  return sectionView;
}
```

In the textfield delegate, get the section index from the sender's parent:

```
- (void) textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField; 
{
  NSInteger theSectionIndex = textField.superview.tag;
  // your custom logic here
}
```

Comment: you're absolutely right, this would work. I should have mentioned however, I have already assigned a tag to the to distinguish it from other uitextfields I have in the cells in the table.

Comment: Updated my answer. Set the tags on the sectionView (assuming you're not using that).

Answer (score 0):

You would probably want to look into UITableView method indexPathForCell:.

You can get the cell through view hierarchy from your UITextField, since it's in your Cell's contentView.

Regards,

sven.

Comment: Do headers and footers have indexPaths? If they do that will do it, but I thought only cells had them.

Comment: They don't. I'm sorry, I misread the part of your question where you mentioned headers.

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple Mr.Ben Thompson. You have named different between each one to UITextFields am i right?. Just find the specific UITextField by used it's name.

```
-(void) textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if (textField == textfieldOne) 
    {
        //Do whatever you want...
    }
    else if (textField == textfieldTwo)
    {
        //Do whatever you want...
    }
    else if (textField == textfieldThree)
    {
        //Do whatever you want...
    }
}
```

I hope it will help you a little bit. Thanks.

Comment: As the cells are created at runtime programatically, they are all instances of the same cell so have the same name. Otherwise a good suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

i believe you add the field as a custom view to the header in `viewForHeader` method of `tableview`.

I suggest keeping a tag of the field using the section like this.

```
textfield.tag == section;
```

then in the delegate message you can have a switch method to compare tags..and do your own code there

Comment: I should have mentioned, I have lots of other UITextFields on the same page all with different tags. I am already assigning a tag to the cell to determine that it is a 'header' textField. So I dont think I can use tags.

Comment: edit your question and add the code where you add the tags to text field...add the whole portion of cell for row. also for header view..